# 400 Bad Request (error code: 50006): Cannot send an empty message when replying to user message as bot

Tags: python, discord.py

```
def run_discord_bot():

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
intents.messages = True
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"{client.user} is now running")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    #niet in een oneindige loop komen
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    #Get data about user
    username = str(message.author).split('#')[0]
    user_message = str(message.content)
    channel = str(message.channel)

    #debug printing
    print(f"{username} said: '{user_message}' ({channel})")

    if user_message == 'hi':
        await message.reply(f'hi {username}')

    if user_message[0] == "?":
        user_message = user_message[1:] #removes the ?
        await send_message(message, user_message, is_private=True)
    else:
        await send_message(message, user_message, is_private=False)
```

When I run the code it does its job and replies to the user, but in the terminal I get this error message `400 Bad Request (error code: 50006): Cannot send an empty message` . And it only does this when responding to messages not when it runs commands.

Comment: What is `send_message`? Please include a [mcve] and the full stack trace of the error you are getting. For more information, please see [ask].

Answer (score -2):

Just use `await message.channel.send()` to send text whenever needed.

Give it an upvote if it works. ty!